# Show Arabic on Android device

Tags: android, text, fonts, arabic

I am displaying Arabic text on Android with some font and arabic reshaper. It's not displaying well.

Kindly guide me with Arabic text of whole Qur'an with settings of some font that can be displayed on All Android devices those have Arabic installed or not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android/7962813#7962813

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Arabic is not supported until Android 3.0

If you are talking about the Holy Quran, then the best suggestion I can give you is using images for versions older than 3.0 and the regular text for the earlier ones.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this helps, assuming you have an arabic font: http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-using-custom-fonts/

Shouldn't matter what else they have installed.

Comment: yes, i am using like this. but arabic characters are disturbing

Comment: They're ok once you get to know them.

Comment: You can find your solution [at this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7962813/779408). Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PDMS_Islamicfont , me_quran, ZekrQuran

but u need little changes. if you need font file. modified give me your email id. i will send